# how to move a number's high 8 bits 7 times in c or python?

Tags: python, c, assembly, bit

For example:    `EAX = 10101010 00001110 11001010 00100000`

I want to move EAX high 8 bits to right 7 times,what can i do in c or in python?

In asm :    `SHR ah,7`

The result of EAX is:`10101010 00001110 00000001 00100000`

And how about     `SHR ax,7`?

I have tried ((EAX & 0xff00) >> 8 ) >> 7,but i don't how to add it back to EAX?

Comment: To assign it back to `EAX`, just put `EAX =` on the left side of that expression. (You could also use `>>=` instead of `>>`.) Is that what you're asking?

Comment: are you sure about the desired result ?

Comment: `((EAX & 0xff00) >> 8 ) >> 7` would be the equivalent of `EAX >> 15`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with:

In C\C++: `EAX = (EAX & 0xFFFF00FF) | (((EAX & 0x0000FF00) >> 7) & 0x0000FF00)`

In more expanded C\C++ code would be:

```
unsigned long shift_count = 7;
unsigned long mask = 0x0000FF00;
EAX = (EAX & (~mask)) | (((EAX & mask) >> shift_count) & mask)
```

Change `mask` and `shift_count` to match your needs.

Where `EAX` is the variable holding the value, `0x0000FF00` is the mask of the interesting byte and `0xFFFF00FF` is the inverse of the previous mask.

Comment: Too much masking. Take advantage of the bits falling off.

Comment: What masking do you think is not needed?

Comment: If you don't do the third one the bits from bits 8-15, that go to the position 0-7 by the shift would mess the final result. Test with `eax = 0xAA0ECA20` the same binary in the question, the result with the method i propose is `0xAA0E0120`, without the last masking is `0xAA0E01B4`, the lowest byte was not correct. According to the question the behavior wanted is as a shift to `AH` was made.

Comment: Try `EAX = (EAX & ~0xFF00) | ((EAX >> 7) & 0x100)`. @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Your comments don't help. If you want to say something, just say it directly.

Comment: Note that the above results from replacing your general expression with: `EAX = (EAX & ~mask) | ((EAX >> shift_count) & ((mask >> shift_count) & mask))`

Answer (score -1):

You can store bits from 9th onwards in other variable. Then make those vits 0 in EAX. Then do EAX << 7 and add those bits again to it.